# MS Graph API search by keyword on Microsoft 365 Calendar events using c#

Tags: c#, events, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I need to search by keyword, so that I could retrieve only events that contain this keyword I am searching for.
I already got an answer that solves part of my problem (filter on subject),
but I still need to search on bodypreview too.

I am trying to add my search (or filter) parameter on this piece of code:

...

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        // Get start and end of week in user's time zone
        // I replaced variables below by pure strings on QueryOption <== DOES WORKS FINE
        //var startOfWeek = GetUtcStartOfWeekInTimeZone(DateTime.Today, App.UserTimeZone);
        //var endOfWeek = startOfWeek.AddDays(30);  //Eloir: original AddDays(7)

        var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>
        {
            //new QueryOption("$search", "BodyPreview:stackoverflow"),  <== DOES NOT WORK
            new QueryOption("startDateTime", "01/01/2020 00:00:00"),  
            new QueryOption("endDateTime", "31/12/2020 23:59:59")

        };

        var timeZoneString =
            Xamarin.Forms.Device.RuntimePlatform == Xamarin.Forms.Device.UWP ?
                App.UserTimeZone.StandardName : App.UserTimeZone.DisplayName;

        // Get the events
        var events = await App.GraphClient.Me.CalendarView.Request(queryOptions)
            .Header("Prefer", $"outlook.timezone=\"{timeZoneString}\"")
            //.Filter("BodyPreview contains 'stackoverflow'")  <== DOES NOT WORK EITHER

            .Select(e => new
            {
                e.Subject,
                e.BodyPreview,
                e.Start,
                e.End
            })
            .OrderBy("start/DateTime")
            .Top(50)
            .GetAsync();

        // Add the events to the list view
        CalendarList.ItemsSource = events.CurrentPage.ToList();

    }
```

...
This code is part of Microsoft docs site:
**[Build Xamarin apps with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/xamarin)**

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/search-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#keyword-query-language-kql-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CalendarView provides the list of expanded events in the specified time range only and does not support additional filtering.

You can use me/events endpoint to filter by a `dateTime` and `subject` or `bodyPreview`

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=start/dateTime ge '2021-09-06T08:00' and end/dateTime lt '2021-09-30T08:00' and contains(subject,'planning')
```

C#

```
await App.GraphClient.Me.Events.Request()
    .Filter("start/dateTime ge '2021-09-06T08:00' and end/dateTime lt '2021-09-30T08:00' and contains(subject,'planning')")
    .Select(e => new
        {
            e.Subject,
            e.BodyPreview,
            e.Start,
            e.End
        })
        .OrderBy("start/DateTime")
        .Top(50)
        .GetAsync();
```

Comment: thank you very very much.
It worked just like I needed.

Comment: Hello user2250152
I realized that _filter_ does not work on _BodyPreview_ field, even when using ._Events.Request()_.
So, is it possible to add a $Search parameter on BodyPreview field, too?
Thankyou in advance.